# Bulk upload data in HDFS to elasticsearch server

Tags: json, unix, hadoop, solr, elasticsearch

I have a large dataset in HDFS in CSV format that I need to bulk upload to ElasticSearch server. Is there a way to bulk upload this data from HDFS using unix command line?

I have done this in SOLR (https://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateCSV) using some simple shell command like :

```
hadoop fs -ls <dir-name> | awk '{ print $NF }'| 
while read inDir ; do hadoop fs -cat $inDir | 
parallel --pipe --block 50000 curl -v --data-binary @- -H 
"Content-type:text/plain” ‘http://localhost:8983/solr/update/csv?commit=false\&fieldnames=name,address,city' ; 
done
```

Is there a similar way/tools which I can read the data from HDFS files, convert it into nicely formatted JSON and stream it to ElasticSearch server for bulk indexing ? The other option is that I use Java/Python to do this processing. I just wanted to explore if there is simple set of unix tools that can be used to achieve the same thing.

Thanks.